# Swiper wrong direction on multi row, direction: horizontally and slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

I'm currently using Swiper:

1. Swiper Version: 4.5.0.
2. Platform/Target and Browser Versions: Web Chrome.
3. Correct behaviour if exactly 12 items: https://codepen.io/chunallen/pen/gOYGOpo
4. Incorrect behaviour if more than 12 items: https://codepen.io/chunallen/pen/QWLqWbJ

#### Current Behaviour

I have a multi row grid of cards that should show 12 cards per page. I'm iterating to a 18 items or sometimes dynamic but it should render at least 12 items per page

```
options = {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      slidesPerColumn: 4,
      slidesPerGroup:3,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      slidesPerColumnFill: 'row',
      direction: 'horizontal',
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
     }
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

If I have 18 items It should show in order horizontally and 12 per page
like this:

```
for 1st page
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
10| 11| 12

for 2nd page
13 | 14 | 15
16 | 17 | 18
```

#### Actual Behavior

If I'm rending more that 12 for example 18 or more, the directions from 1-12 goes to 2nd page.

```
for 1st page
1 | 2 | 3
6 | 7 | 8
11| 12| 13
16| 17| 18


for 2nd page
3 | 4 | 5
8 | 9 | 10
18
```

Please check this for reference https://codepen.io/chunallen/pen/QWLqWbJ

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by answering my own raised issue on Github https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3193